# Create A Custom Keyboard on Android with emoji

Tags: android, keyboard, emoji

i used [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-keyboard-on-android--cms-22615) for make keybaord. and i import this madule in my project in android studio. after search for 2-3 hours i can't use this emojis
[rockerhieu_emojicon](https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon) is A library to show emoji in TextView, EditText (like WhatsApp) for Android.
i want to make android emoji custom keybard.
how to start? thank you